# Android GridView Auto Scrolls to First Ready Item

Tags: android

I have a GridView that displays both images and videos. The getView methods returns ImageView or VideoView depends on the type of the next available data in the adapter. When video is loading, I'm using a FrameLayout to block out an area to display a loading placeholder.

Because video loading always takes longer and video data always precedes image data in the list, whenever I go into the activity, the **GridView automatically scrolls down to the first available image**, which is not what I want. Even when I scroll back, it will scroll down later automatically to the border between VideoView and ImageView. I just want to disable this functionality.

I've done some research and tried

```
mGridView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

But the problem still exists. Thanks.